# How to get data from database in Microsoft BOT Framework 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework

I am building a chatbot using Microsoft bot framework 4. I would like to store the dialog contents in a SQL Server database and would like to retrieve them using the entity framework.

I tried to add code that get data from the database but the emulator reports errors. Following is my code:

```
        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                var start = GetStartDialog();

                if (start != null) {
                    var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                    var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
                    var b = new HeroCard() { Title = start.Title, Text = start.Body, Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { new CardAction() { Title = "Option 1", Value = 1, Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack }, new CardAction() { Title = "Option 2", Value = 2, Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack } } };
                    reply.Attachments.Add(b.ToAttachment());

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }

        public Dialog GetStartDialog()
    {
        BOTEntities db = new BOTEntities();
        Dialog retVal = db.Dialogs.Where(o => o.DialogID.Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault();
        return retVal;
    }
```

Any ideas as to why my code is not executing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already considered it, please look over the [Entity Framework storage](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework) extension available from the BotBuilder-Community repo.

It is designed for v4 of the Bot Builder .NET SDK and can be installed via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework/).

In short, you include the state storage components and then attach the `EntityFrameworkTranscriptStore()`. This will allow you to connect to and execute your script(s) for creating tables, etc.

As this is a built out solution, this may alleviate the error(s) you are receiving.

Hope of help!